# matrix to three columns reset_index()

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have matrix that looks like this:

```
   A  B  C  D
A  0  3  2  5
B -1  0  2  9
C -1 -1  0  8
D -1 -1 -1  0
```

and columns and row have the same label. I am trying to convert matrix to three rows but when I try to use

```
df6 = df4.stack().reset_index()
```

I get an error: `cannot insert name, already exists`

EDIT:

That is the code for creating matrix:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=df3['name'], index=df3['name'])
```

when I delete columns and indexes in above code, there is no error. But I want to keep names of columns.

Comment: I do not get an error, can you please share your code? What is your expected outcome?

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar I've added more description

Comment: What is `df3`? When I run `df4 = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])` it works fine with by me

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, running`df4.stack()` will return something like

```
name   name 
name1  name1    1
       name2    2
       name3    3
name2  name1    4
       name2    5
       name3    6
name3  name1    7
       name2    8
       name3    9
dtype: int64
```

As your indexes have the same index name 'name' and 'name', it returns the error when running `reset_index`.

You can modify the index name before running `reset_index` and it shall work.

```
df5 = df4.stack()
df5.index.names = ['name1', 'name2']
df6 = df5.reset_index()
```